# Convierta DATETIME() a DATE() en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo un sistema de registro donde las entradas realizadas tienen un campo en mysql de tipo DATETIME(). Sin embargo, necesito crear una búsqueda por fecha en el siguiente formato: 2022-11-23 y cuando hago esta búsqueda, no trae resultados, incluso teniendo datos en la tabla, porque el campo es DATETIME().

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexão,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_date = '2022-11-23';
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa la función `DATE` para extraer la parte de la fecha:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE(user_date) = '2022-11-23'
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el campo **`user_date`** es **`DATETIME()`**, podrías usar la función **`DATE()`** para que hagas la búsqueda en base a lo que está convertido:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexão,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE(user_date) = '2022-11-23';
```